# Unable to run Tkinter and Flask at the same time

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, asynchronous, flask, tkinter

I have the demo.py code where I let's say open the Web-Cam in tkinter window. Now, I also have flask code to display hello @localhost.

When I run the demo.py file it runs the function that I write first For ex:

```
import libraries

Flask code

Tkinter code

if __name__ == '__main__':

    window.mainloop() #for tkinter This will run first
    app.run() #for flask This will run when I close the Tkinter windows
```

How can I run both at the same time ?

Comment: Seems like quite similar question https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/537645/python-flask-%D0%B8-tkinter

Comment: I was able to solve this problem using Threading.